# Convert HTML to NSAttributedString in iOS - Don't Get Colors in NSAttributed String

Tags: html, iphone, objective-c, nsattributedstring, core-text

I created the iOS 7 method below to convert an HTML string to NSAttributedString. (I do realize `initWithString:attributes:` should work instead of `initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:`; I've tried both.)

The resulting attributed string I get properly removes the HTML tags from the input, including color, and properly applies bold, italic, and underline, but fails to apply attributes to the output string for color or lists. I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this behavior and found a fix?

```
+ (NSAttributedString*)stringWithHTML:(NSString*)s
{
    NSData* sData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:[s UTF8String] length:s.length];
    NSDictionary* attrs = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute : @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)};
    NSError* err;
    NSAttributedString* aString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:sData options:attrs documentAttributes:nil error:&err];
    return aString;
}
```

So, to provide a concrete example, for the input

```
@"<red><i>Sim</red><color=00ffff>ple</color><blue>string.</i></blue>"
```

I get the result

```
Simple string.{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0xc3710b0> font-family: \"TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not valid HTML, that's why it's not working. Colors are part of [`styles`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) or (legacy) [`font`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp) tags.

Comment: That is an incredibly good point. Why I took for granted it was is beyond explanation.